Is the Butterworth filter really a limiting case of Chebychev
I have heard that said, and it sounds vaguely plausible, but my maths is not up to proving it.  Here is why:
The Ideal n-th order Butterworth response, in terms of S-parameters, is
$$
|s21|^2 = \frac{1}{1 + \omega^{2n}}
$$
On the other hand, the Chebychev ideal resonse is
$$
|s21|^2 = \frac{1}{1 + \epsilon^2 T_n^{2}(\omega)}
$$
As I see it, as \$\epsilon\$ approaches zero, \$|s21|^2\$ approaches one identically.  Is my initial assumption wrong, or is there some mathematical magic that can come up with a different form of the limit for Chebychev with \$\epsilon\$ approaching zero?
For example, I can imagine the (semi-)circular pole-zero plot for Butterworth "morphing" from a circle into an ellipse, but I can't relate that to the transfer function.
[EDIT] On thinking about this more, perhaps the comparison can only be made when the cutoff specifications for the two types are identical (3db frequency, 1db etc).  In this case, the "cutoff frequency" for zero ripple Chebychev would be \$\infty\$, making a direct comparison impossible.
I think this just needs a restatement of the Butterworth power transfer function as follows
$$
|s21|^2 = \frac{1}{1 + k\omega^{2n}}
$$
to allow a cutoff value other than 3db and enable the direct comparison where appropriate.

I don't understand your question title.

@Andyaka I have read somewhere that the Butterworth filter is the limiting case of Chebychev, when $\epsilon$ approaches zero.  I would like to know whether this is true, and if so how to show it.

My advice is that you find that assertion on line and link it into your question.

FWIW, I understood the title and question perfectly (I think); but I don't have the analytical theory necessary to address it.

@Andyaka I am looking, but perhaps it is just an old assumption of mine (my final year filters course was in 1985!) - I came at this recently while looking for "real-world" models for optimization ;)

Do you understand that all the pole pairs of a Butterworth filter have the same inherent natural frequency hence, they lie on a common circle in the pole-zero diagram. The different positions on the circle that the pole pairs lie is due to different damping ratios whereas.... for a Chebyshev filter.... the different pole pairs do not have the same inherent natural frequency and hence each pole-pair (that forms a 2nd order system) must lie on it's own 2nd order circle in the p-z diagram. Hence, I think your question is a bit meaningless really.

@Andyaka if you are saying that a "zero-ripple" Chebychev filter would have all its poles on the imaginary axis, then yes, I think I get it now ;)

No, I'm not saying that. I'm saying that I don't understand your title question but, in terms of poles, butterworth and chebychev are distinctly different.

I think what needs to be done is to somehow transform $\epsilon \cdot T_n(\omega)$ into $\omega^n$, which doesn't seem possible.  It doesn't help that $T_n(\omega)$ is defined piecewise between where $|\omega|=1$, but regardless, adjusting it while $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ such that it becomes $\omega^n$ hurts my brain.

Perhaps these snaps from Section 8.5 of Van Valkenburg may assist you in some way?  1 2 3 4 5

Compare a low-pass Cheby filter with a low-pass Butterworth filter. Both have a -3dB point near 100 MHz:

Chebychev:
passband ripple: 0.000005 (a fairly small value above zero)
cutoff frequency: 16.3MHz (-3dB will be at a much higher frequency...100 MHz)
RL=RS=50 ohms (arbitrary choice)

The Butterworth filter has similar RL,RS, and a simple 100 MHz cutoff frequency of 100 MHz. That is, the -3dB point is at 100 MHz.:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
These examples seem to converge.
The problem is that convergence fails when Chebychev passband ripple input specification goes to 0dB, as it should to match flat Butterworth passband. In this example, Chebychev passband ripple has been made very, very small, and cutoff frequency adjusted to 16.3 MHz (which results in a -3dB point near 100 MHz).

The empirical result seems motivating -- but the question asks for an answer in terms of poles; can this be proven analytically?
